# LINQ поиск в коллекции коллекций

Tags: c#, linq

Есть некий базовый класс, представляющий узел дерева элеметнов:

```
class TreeITem
{
   public bool Enabled {get;set;}
}
```

Е есть два его наследника: обычный узел и катало (у которого есть подэлементы типа `ITreeItem`). В общем-то получается что-то похожее на папки и файлы.

Класс файла:

```
class FileItem : TreeItem
{
   ...
}
```

Класс папки:

```
class FolderItem : TreeItem
{
    ....

    public Collection<ITreeItem> SubItems {get;set;}
}
```

И в конечном итоге будем работать с коллекцией TreeItem:

```
Collection<TreeItem> AllItems
```

Вопрос в следующем: как при помощи `LINQ` найти все экземпляры-наследники `TreeItem` в `AllItems` у которых, скажем, поле `Enabled == true`? Пробовал с помощью `SelectMany`, но что-то никак не получается - первого и воторого уровня элементы достаю, а дальше не идет.

Вообще вопрос сводится к тому как это дерево вытянуть в список, а там уже найти из них по условию не проблема. Интересует именно вариант через `LINQ`

Comment: >Вопрос в следующем: как при помощи LINQ найти все экземпляры-наследники TreeItem в AllItems у которых, скажем, поле Enabled == true? 

не очень понятен вопрос, что именно вам нужно. Судя по этой формулировке, вам нужна такая лямбда: 

    AllItems.Where(x => x.Enabled)

Comment: @DreamChild, такая лямбда найдет только все елементы первого уровня. А в первом уровне (как и на остальных) может быть элемент типа `FolderItem`, а унего в свою очередь еще коллекция подэлементов, и там тоже может быть `FolderItem`. Дак вот я хочу достать их все

Comment: @Donil нет, я не предлагал вам эту лямбду, я хотел попросить вас сформулировать ваш вопрос более явно

Comment: Эммм... даже не знаю что добавить. В общем представить дерево элементов. Элемент может быть типа `FileItem` (у него нет дочерних) или `FolderItem` (у него могут быть дочение элементы типа `FileItem` или `FolderItem`) и так далее. Дак вот я хочу получить все элементы, не зависимо от уровня вложенности. Так понятнее? Найти все файлы и папки в директории у которых поле `Enabled = true` не зависимо как глубоко они лежат - это если к анологии с файлами/папками

Comment: нет-нет, я, кажется, понял, что вы хотите, сейчас напишу ответ, впрочем, не думаю, что он будет для вас идеален

Comment: Можно взглянуть [здесь][1] и [здесь][2].


  [1]: http://blog.zwezdin.com/ru/101
  [2]: http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2006/07/09/Hierarchical-Linq-Queries.aspx

Comment: @Freezze, там же расширение делается? Меня же интересует возможность это сделать без расширений. Просто интересно возможно ли это:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут есть определенная сложность, благодаря чему реализация исключительно с помощью LINQ вряд ли возможна (пусть меня поправят, если я ошибаюсь). Дело в том, что ваша структура древовидна, а потому ее обход должен осуществляться с помощью рекурсии. А рекурсия подразумевает отказ от анонимных функций, поскольку анонимная функция не может вызывать сама себя, поскольку она анонимна.

Могу предложить что-то наподобие:

```
// ваш TreeItem, никаких изменений
public class TreeITem
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

// тут тоже все по-прежнему
public class FileItem : TreeITem
{

}

public class FolderItem : TreeITem 
{
    public Collection<TreeITem> SubItems { get; set; }

    // это свойство заполнено содержимым для иллюстрации работы
    // как можно видеть, есть только 4 удовлетворяющих условию элемента
    public static Collection<TreeITem> AllItems = new Collection<TreeITem>
    {
        new TreeITem  { Enabled = true }, 
        new TreeITem(), 
        new FolderItem
        {
            SubItems = new Collection<TreeITem>
            {
                new TreeITem { Enabled = true }, 
                new TreeITem { Enabled = true }, 
                new TreeITem { Enabled = false }, 
                new TreeITem { Enabled = true }, 
                new FileItem(), 
                new TreeITem()
            }
        }, 
        new FileItem(), 
    };

    // сама рекурсивная функция
    private static IList<TreeITem> Select(IEnumerable<TreeITem> source, 
                                          Func<TreeITem, bool> predicate)
    {
        var res = new List<TreeITem>();
        foreach (var treeITem in source)
        {
            var folder = treeITem as FolderItem;
            if (folder != null)
                res.AddRange(Select(folder.SubItems, predicate));

            if(predicate(treeITem))
                res.Add(treeITem);
        }
        return res;
    }

    // внешняя обертка а-ля LINQ, работающая через предикат
    public static IList<TreeITem> Select(Func<TreeITem, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Select(AllItems, predicate);
    }
}

....

var res = FolderItem.Select(x => x.Enabled);
// будет выведено 4 - количество вложенных элементов с Enabled == true 
Console.WriteLine(res.Count());
```

Comment: Вот и я не смог придумать как это сделать с `LINQ`:) Сделал через рекурсию, но все-таки думаю дай спрошу, мало ли. Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: все же LINQ - это не серебряная пуля, и с его помощью можно сделать отнюдь не всё